# How to build windows 10 universal app package for the store

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

I try to build UWP app package for publishing in the store with Visual Studio 2015 RC. I follow the same procedure as I do for windows 8.1 app:

Project -> Store -> Create App Packages.

But I can't choose *"yes"* in *"Do you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Store"* checkbox because it's disabled.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to prepare and upload UWP app to the windows 10
   store, now?
2. If no, when will I be able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here:

The store isn't yet open for Windows 10 apps. You won't be able to upload them until it is.

The final SDK has not yet been released. You'll need to rebuild your app with the released version once it is available on 29 July.

See [Release Dates and Compatibility: Visual Studio 2015 and the Windows 10 SDK](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/29/release-dates-and-compatibility-visual-studio-2015-and-windows-10-sdk/) for details.

To prepare, build and test your app on the latest available SDK ([currently 10166](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/07/09/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-10166-released/))